# reverse base64 encode and gzcompress

Tags: php, file, reverse

```
@file_put_contents('http://somesite.com/somefile.txt', str_replace("=", "", base64_encode(gzcompress($date_of_birth . " : " . $data['username'], FILE_APPEND);
```

How do i reverse the base64 encoding and gzcompress and save it to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PHP Documentation: in the [`gzcompress`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) page you'll find the [`gzuncompress`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) function, in the [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) you'll find the [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function.